# Using VBA to copy data from excel to powerpoint - Error

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to use VBA to copy data from excel to powerpoint. I've got the following code which I believe should work but it keeps giving me an error even though I've declared and specific all of the variables.

```
Sub CopyToPPT()

Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim myShapeRange As Range


DestinationPPT = "C:\powerpoint.pptx"

'Open Powerpoint
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)


Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:D14")

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(5)
Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
'Copy
rng.copy
'Paste
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)


  myShapeRange.Left = 234
  myShapeRange.Top = 186





End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to like the line

```
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
```

Any idea how I can fix this? When I try running it I get the error:

Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Instead of saving it to the root folder of `C:`,  try saving it to your `Desktop` folder and change the path in your code. If that doesnt work, tell us what the error message is. Is it "file not found"?

Comment: Seems, you haven't create new instance of PP. PP should be opened first ;) `Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application`

Comment: the file isn't really in the root of my C drive, it's actually in my documents folder but I just modified it for this post to avoid posting anything that may be confidential

Comment: What's error message?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: IOW "I get *an error*" isn't helpful information. *What is the error*?

Comment: I've edited the original post, the error message is: Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Then read [@MaciejLos's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162475/using-vba-to-copy-data-from-excel-to-powerpoint-error#comment81274657_47162475) (and answer, once he un-deletes it) *carefully* - for that is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i'd strongly recommend to read about [Early and late binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/)

You have to create new instance of PowerPoint application before you'll try to open presentation.

This should work:

```
'your code 
Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
'the rest of your code
'Open Powerpoint
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
```